# Phonon with vlc backend on Windows

Tags: qt, pyqt, vlc, pyside, libvlc

I'm trying to make an media player application with pyQt/pyside and the phonon library. 
Currently I'm using the default backend (phonon_ds94.dll). I would like to use the phonon_vlc.dll one but I don't know how to make the switch on winXP. Any one have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project:

http://code.google.com/p/subsonic-client/

It's a client for [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org), but it's written in PyQt and uses VLC as its back-end. The project tried to use Phonon to start with but found that it wasn't flexible enough with different audio formats and that it completely failed with transcoded audio as it doesn’t provide a content-length header.

I'm not sure if things have changed with this, but the source code is there for you to have a look at and play with.